# Send empty array with Alamofire API Rest

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I want to send an empty array to a Rest Full API by using patch method. But i don't know why it is not working. In fact, i am also using postman for testing my requests, and this request works fine in postman ( I want  wordTrads be empty )  :

[image]

And this is how i've implemented that API called in Swift by using Alamofire :

```
let parameters = [
     "wordTrads" : [],
]
Alamofire.request("\(Auth.URL_API)/lists/205",method: .patch, parameters : parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
   print("List patched")
}
```

But in swift it's not working like if Alamofire doesn't send empty arrays.

I am using Alamofire 4.6.0 and Swift 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen snapshots suggest you're expecting to send JSON, but your Alamofire syntax is not doing that. You need to add `encoding` of `JSONEncoding.default` if you want to send JSON:

```
let parameters = [
     "wordTrads" : []
]

Alamofire.request("\(Auth.URL_API)/lists/205", method: .patch, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value): print(value)
        case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
}
```

And if you do that, the body of the request includes that empty array in JSON form:

```
{"wordTrads":[]}
```